# Running a function with multiple arguments when an argument is not used

Tags: r, function

I think my question can be made quite generic and simple, so that I will not give the concrete function that I am trying to make.

I have a function that changes its behaviour according to its first argument:

```
example <- function(arg1 = T,
                    arg2 = NULL,
                    arg3,
                    ...) {
  if (arg1 != T) {

    final <- bind_rows(arg2)

  } else{
    list1 <- list(...)
    final <- bind_rows(list1, arg3)

  }


  return(final)
}
```

My issue is that if I run `example(arg1 = T, arg3 = x, c(A,B), c(C,D))`, considering that the user of my function probably won't write out anything for `arg2`, I have a problem. `c(A,B)` ends up not being considered the first element of `list1` (I guess it is assigned to `arg2` and then goes unused in the function) and I have `bind_rows(c(C,D), x)` as the output, instead of `bind_rows(c(A,B), c(C,D), x)`.

How can this be fixed, considering that the function is not for personal use, but for a larger package?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think `arg2` cannot be skipped for the way it is written. However, I think `example(arg1 = T, arg3 = x, ,c(A,B), c(C,D))` might work though.

Comment: Consider that the ellipsis doesn't need to be the last argument of the function.  If users need to use `arg2` then they can name it.

Comment: As an aside: Better write `TRUE` instead of `T` and then do `if(!arg1) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put arg2 in `...`

```
example <- function(arg1 = T,
                    arg3,
                    ...) {
  args <- list(...)
  if (is.null(args$arg2) & arg1==F) {stop("arg2 needed when arg1==F")}

  if (arg1 != T) {

    final <- list(arg2)

  } else{
    list1 <- list(...)
    final <- list(list1, arg3)

  }


  return(final)
}
```

Comment: But this would probably confuse the user, since ```...``` would include arg2 and the list of vectors, which have completely diferent natures, wouldn't it? I

Comment: the user should name arg2 = val in the call to the function : example(T, arg2 =1,c(5,4,3))

Comment: It would work, my point is that with  ```...``` and no explicit ```arg2``` in the function's main arguments, the user wouldn't know that if arg1 != F, there needs to be something in named arg2

Comment: see my edit : I added an error message in this case

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly enough, you can switch the order of your arguments and have those dots first.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

ex <- function(...,
               arg1 = T,
               arg2 = NULL,
               arg3) {
  if (arg1 != T) {
    final <- bind_rows(arg2)
  } else{
    list1 <- list(...)
    final <- bind_rows(list1, arg3)
  }
  return(final)
}

ex(arg1 = T, arg3 = iris[1, ], iris[2, ], iris[3, ])
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 3          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I don't know if this is advised (and I'm hesitant to suggest this), but it does solve your issue using the code you've provided. The answer proposed by [@Waldi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62297125/6873133) is a much better solution to your problem.