# Using ellipsis in nested functions

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

this question is related to this previous one: [Running a function with multiple arguments when an argument is not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296913/running-a-function-with-multiple-arguments-when-an-argument-is-not-used?noredirect=1#comment110180756_62296913)

I have two functions, `original` and `example` that will be in a future package. `example` will follow an `if/else` structure and on one of those branches (if `arg1 = T`), it runs `original` inside it. It goes as follows:

**EDIT: Giving a more realistic example than before**

```
  original <- function(start, ...) {
  list1 = list(...)

if (any(map(list1, length) != 2)) {stop('ERROR! Each vector must have length 2')}
  df = read.csv(start)
  final <- bind_rows(list1, df)
  return(final)
}




       example <- function(arg1 = TRUE, ...) {
          args<- list(...)

      if (!(arg1) & is.null(args$arg2)) {stop("If arg1 == F, arg2 is needed.")}

      if(arg1 == TRUE & is.null(argumentos$arg3)){stop("If arg1 == T, arg3 is needed.")}

      if (arg1 != TRUE) {

            final <- bind_rows(arg2)
} else{

            arg3 <- args$arg3
            args$arg3 <- NULL
            final <- original(start = arg3, args)

              }


              return(final)
            }
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:** Is it okay to nest functions like that? 
  My main issue is, how can I ensure that elements that form `list1` in `original` will now be formed by the entries in the ellipsis `...` on `example`'s call? I can't simply enclose the latter on a list since `original` itself already would do that.

**EDIT** My main issue is that a typical call in `original` is of the form `original(start, c(1, 2000), c(2, 2001), c(3,2001))`.

Running in my computer, I get problems because when I run `example` with `example(arg1 = TRUE, arg3 = './Desktop', c(1, 2000), c(2, 2001), c(3,2001))`, I want `R` to compute, through `example()`, `original(start = './Desktop', c(2, 2001), c(3,2001))`.

But R crashes, giving me the original stop message from the first function:

```
ERROR! Each vector must have length 2
```

This happens only when there is more than one vector after `arg3`.

Maybe my function is instead running `original(start = './Desktop', '.Desktop', c(2, 2001, 3 ,2001))`,

Can someone help me correct this?

Comment: You can nest functions as much as you want and the `...` will flow thru.   **WARNING** do not use "T" when you mean "TRUE" because sooner or later it will lead to sadness.  One other thing, assuming `arg1` is logical,  just do `if ( !arg1)`

Comment: thank you! Does this warning applies to F/FALSE as well? Do you mean that only when writing functions?

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid "F" as well - but "T" is particularly troublesome to the genetics community, who need to process DNA sequences :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft In my case the ... don't flow through. Please check the edit for an explanation

Comment: It seems like `...` includes `arg3` when you call `example`, but then you want to remove `arg3` from `...` before passing it along to `original()`. I'm not sure how to do that, but I think that's what you're having this problem here.

Comment: One way I've thought was to run  ```original(arg3, vectors)``` inside ```example```, instead of ```original(arg3, ...)```, where ```vectors``` would be the sequence of vectors ```c(1,2000)```, ```c(1,2001)```... But I don't know how to pass those to original without considering them a list inside the function call

Comment: @GregorThomas I've edited the question including the progress I've made, as I said in the previous comment.

Comment: Passing them as a list seems an easy solution. If you're okay with `example(arg1, arg3, orig_args = list(c(1, 2000), c(1, 2001)))`, you can then use `do.call(original, c(arg1, orig_args))`, which is equivalent to `original(arg1, orig_args[[1]], org_args[[2]], ...)`

Comment: I guess it's easier to do that way, thanks!